# Parsing Previous node from any where within the HTML using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have following scenario. I have following sample html. I need to parse this.I am using HtmlAgilityPack using VB.Net

```
<h1>Category 1</h1>
...
...
<h4><a>c1</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c2</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c3</a> </h4>

<h1>Category 2</h1>
...
...
<h4><a>c4</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c5</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c6</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c7</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c8</a> </h4>

<h1>Category 3</h1>
...
...
<h4><a>c9</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c10</a> </h4>
<h4><a>c11</a> </h4>
```

I have list of all h4 tags. How I can find the previous H1 heading text using HtmlAgilityPack? For example I should have

```
For <a> c3 ..... I should have <h1> Category 1
For <a> c6 ..... I should have <h1> Category 2
For <a> c9 ..... I should have <h1> Category 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to look for previous h1. But this will mess it up when 1 h1 is missing.
I am not familiar with HtmlAgilityPack in VB.NET so I wrote it in C#. Just to give you an idea.

`var headingNode = node.PreviousSibling;
                while (headingNode != null && (headingNode.Name.Equals("h4") || headingNode.Name.Equals("#text")))
                {
                    headingNode = headingNode.PreviousSibling;
                }
//We will have first non h4 or #text here`

Comment: The solution is perfect. Only one change I did in while condition, I need to compare for "h1" with Not operator